# Cannot determine timezone from nil \n (secs :xxxxxx.xxx, utc~:\""

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, logstash, elastic-stack, windows-server

Without JDBC all ELK stack working very fine and creating index. But while I try to fetch data from SQL Sevrer it shows error

> Cannot determine timezone from nil\n(secs:1682572498.097,utc~:"2023-04-27 05:14:58.0969998836517334",ltz~:nil)\n(etz:nil,tnz:"NPT",tziv:"2.0.6",tzidv:"1.2022.7",rv:"2.6.8",rp:"java",win:true,rorv:nil,astz:nil,eov:"1.2.7",eotnz:"???",eotnfz:"???",eotlzn:"???",\ndebian:nil,centos:nil,osx:nil)\nTry setting `ENV['TZ'] = 'Continent/City'` in your script*

My Logstash config as follows:

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_connection_string =>  "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestDB;integratedSecurity=false;"
jdbc_driver_library => ""
jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
jdbc_user => "sa"
jdbc_password => "password"
jdbc_default_timezone => "Asia/Kathmandu"
statement => "SELECT * FROM Branches"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch{
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
index => "Branches"
user => "elastic"
password => "password"
}
}
```